# Tippyjs shows content of html tippies for a brief time on page load

Tags: javascript, html, tippyjs

I am using TippyJS to add some tooltips to my website. They have HTML content which works fine, except on page load you can for a short time see the content before it dissapears. How can I fix that? My site jumps now because some HTML of a tippy is in my menu structure.

I simply have these files in my footer:

```
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tippy JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
```

Example of a tooltip that I have:

```
<span class="tooltippy_nostyle">
    <img class="infosvg" src="assets/images/custom/icon_info.svg">
    <div class="tooltipcontent darktext">
    Test
    </div>
</span>
```

And the JS:

```
$( ".tooltippy_nostyle" ).each(function( i ) {
    tippy(this, {
        trigger: 'click',
        allowHTML: true,
        animation: 'scale-subtle',
        interactive: true,
        content: function (reference) {
            return reference.querySelector('.tooltipcontent');
        }
    });
});
```

It does not matter what the content is, alot of html or simply 1 word. The content is shown first before the TippyJS code removes it and puts it inside the tooltip. What can I do to fix this? I tried moving the files in my footer to my header but this changed nothing.

Comment: Hide them with css before JS for tooltips is initialized: `.tooltippy_nostyle {display: none;} `

Comment: @Andrey I tried that but it doesn't work. Only if I add `!important` after it but then the tooltip stays hidden.

Comment: Try to position them offscreen then, then initialised Tippy will take over. But generally it is best to provide reproducible demo